# why knapsack implementation need n as argument

Tags: java, algorithm

When I read solution to knapsack problem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), I couldn't understand why there is iteration number n in the argument. It seems we can come to leaf use case by checking the passed limit. Ex. the 15KG backpack problem, solution seems like:

```
Value(n, W){ // W = limit, n = # items still to choose from
    if (n == 0) return 0;
    if (arr[n][W] != unknown) return arr[n][W]; // <- add memoize
    if (s[n] > W) result = Value(n-1,W);
    else result = max{v[n] + Value(n-1, W-w[n]), Value(n-1, W)};
    arr[n][W] = result;                // <- add memoize
    return result;
}
```

My non-memoize method looks like the below, which is easier to understand, at least for me, and also could be improved with memoization.

```
static int n =5;
static int [] w = new int[]{12,2,1,4,1}; //weight
static int [] v = new int[]{4,2,1,10,2}; //value
public static int knapSack(int wt){
    int maxValue = 0,vtemp = 0, wtemp =0;
    if (wt ==0) return 0;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        if (w[i] > wt) continue;
        int tmp = v[i] + knapSack(wt - w[i]);
        if (tmp > maxValue){
            maxValue = tmp;
            vtemp = v[i];
            wtemp = w[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("wt="+wt + ",vtemp="+vtemp+",wtemp="+wtemp+",ret max="+maxValue);
    return maxValue;
}
```

So my question is:

1. why do we need n for argument?
2. statement if (s[n] > W) result = Value(n-1,W); make me even harder to understand why
3. I see the same big O for memoized version of my approach. Any other difference?

Thanks.

Comment: why don't you have a go at memoizing your version? I think the `first n items` arg starts to make a lot of sense then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're actually solving a different problem. The first piece of code (with `n`) solves the *0-1 knapsack problem*, where you can choose to take at most one of any particular item (i.e. there is no "copying" of items). In that case, you need `n` to keep track of which items you've already used up.

In the second piece of code, you're solving the *unbounded knapsack problem*, in which you can take every item an unlimited number of times.

They're both forms of the NP-complete knapsack problem, but they have different solutions.